# mdadm partitions gone after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, raid, mdadm

I had a RAID 6 setup in Cockpit UI with multiple partitions. There was one partition in particular that I wanted to extend from 10TB to 11TB using available space and attempted on /dev/md127p6 using "growpart /dev/md127p6 1". Afterwards I noticed I could access some of the mount points in the system under this array (two of them actually).

From that point I decided to restart (checked /proc/mdstat and it wasn't doing anything). Once the server came back up all of the partitions were gone for this raid.

Once the server was back online I noticed the size of the raid was different (from 189TiB to 143TiB). Obviously I screwed something up but I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas before I start over.

> mdadm --detail /dev/md127 /dev/md127:
> Version : 1.2
> Creation Time : Mon May 17 20:04:04 2021
> Raid Level : raid6
> Array Size : 153545080832 (146432.00 GiB 157230.16 GB)
> Used Dev Size : 11811160064 (11264.00 GiB 12094.63 GB)
> Raid Devices : 15
> Total Devices : 15
> Persistence : Superblock is persistent
>
> ```
>  Intent Bitmap : Internal
>
>    Update Time : Mon Aug  2 20:05:13 2021
>          State : clean
> Active Devices : 15    Working Devices : 15
> Failed Devices : 0
>  Spare Devices : 0
>
>         Layout : left-symmetric
>     Chunk Size : 4K
> ```
>
> Consistency Policy : bitmap
>
> ```
>           Name : storback:backups
>           UUID : c8d289dd:2cb2ded3:cbcff4cd:1e7367ee
>         Events : 150328
>
> Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
>    0       8       32        0      active sync   /dev/sdc
>    1       8       48        1      active sync   /dev/sdd
>    2       8       64        2      active sync   /dev/sde
>    3       8       80        3      active sync   /dev/sdf
>    4       8       96        4      active sync   /dev/sdg
>    5       8      112        5      active sync   /dev/sdh
>    6       8      128        6      active sync   /dev/sdi
>    7       8      144        7      active sync   /dev/sdj
>    8       8      160        8      active sync   /dev/sdk
>    9       8      192        9      active sync   /dev/sdm
>   10       8      176       10      active sync   /dev/sdl
>   11       8      208       11      active sync   /dev/sdn
>   12       8      224       12      active sync   /dev/sdo
>   13       8      240       13      active sync   /dev/sdp
>   14      65        0       14      active sync   /dev/sdq
> ```

Comment: growpart expects a block device (which contains a partition table) as its first argument, _not_ a partition.

Answer (score 1):

Well since this wasn't a super important device I tried to wing it and grow the raid to the maximum size since the total size was incorrect. It almost appeared as though the raid size shrunk by the amount of free unpartitioned space I had previous.

I ran this command and all the partitions came back after a reboot:

> mdadm --grow /dev/md127 -z max